# How to completely remove the last subnode from a navigation menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to remove the last `li` of sub node which is :

```
<li class="inactive"><a href="/c/8/pregnancy">Pregnancy</a></li>
```

I tried

```
$('.ul-links ul li:last').remove();
```

with no success, any ideas or suggestions where I'm doing wrong, cheers

```
<div class="quiklinks">
   <ul class="ul-links">
      <li><a href="http://localhost:3810/" id="quiklinks_01">Home page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="quiklinks_05">Products</a>
         <ul>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="/c/4/parasitology">Parasitology</a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="/c/5/bacterial-toxins">Bacterial Toxins</a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="/c/6/immunology">Immunology</a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="/c/7/rapid-assayspoc">Rapid Assays/POC</a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="/c/8/pregnancy">Pregnancy</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/t/company" id="quiklinks_07">Company</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below code,

```
$('.ul-links > li > ul > li:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. If the function has to be called after loading the page, wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function(){...})`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ul-links ul li:last').remove();
});
```

See this Fiddle for comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/eRB4x/